# SharePoint Add-in to create workflow in On-premise 2016 environment

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, custom

I need to create Workflow in SharePoint Addin which is associated with Document Library in Host Web(Site)

Task I have performed :-

Created SharePoint Addin -> Added Workflow Item to the project -> It will ask for List/Library created in the App itself.

I need to attach this to the existing document Library in Host Web (Site).

Please provide me some details if any one come across the same requirement.

Comment: It looks like this article will help you: http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html